# Military Strength of an HRE in the 1940's?

Tags: alternate-history, military

How strong would a reincarnation of the Holy Roman Empire be during the 1940s? This includes all of the former Roman Empire's territory (before its collapse) and the Holy Roman Empire's territory.

Comment: As in, *all* of the Roman's Empire territories? It'd control three quarters of Europe and half the Middle East, why? The HRE was a joke compared to the Romans.

Comment: Also, what's the connection? The Holy Roman Empire was, as the saying goes, neither Holy, nor Roman, and not really much of an Empire.

Comment: @Halfthawed Edited to clarify the extent

Comment: At various points in time, the Roman empire consisted of all of Europe, except Scandinavia; Turkey; the Middle East up to the borders of Persia; and the entirety of north Africa

Comment: Sorry, this question is just too broad without further context. Is this an alternate history question, asking what would happen if the Roman Empire never fell? Is this supposing the HRE just managed to gain control of all the land that Rome had? I'm not sure what's being asked.

Comment: How is this world building? That just seems like a random thought that makes little sense with an obvious answer to me. A good world builder would make the HRE as powerful as it needs to be for their world

Comment: Sorry guys. I really just felt like posting something and posted the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Sorry for the OT, but I saw this and had no idea about the acronym, except that it looks similar to "MRE"... and the first that came to mind was "[Humans](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImAHumanitarian), [Ready to Eat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man)?"

Comment: I would add that "the 1940s" is a little vague for what should be obvious reasons.  Military technology, manpower and supplies, control of territory and positioning of troops changed a lot during that decade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reincarnation of the Holy Roman Empire in the 1940's would have an abysmal military strength.

Defensively, the armor employed by by the Holy Roman Empire would in no way stand up to automated machine gun fire or artillery or any kind. The Holy Roman Empire would have no way of protecting its troops from a moderately well equipped army.

Offensively, The Holy Roman Empire is capable of attacking infantry, however the likely of an attack on infantry succeeding would not be high. Even at its peak the Holy Roman Empire would only have access to black powder rifles and primitive cannon technology. Infantry in the 1940's have higher accuracy, rifled gun barrels and much longer range. This is not to mention the complete ineffectiveness the Holy Roman Empire would have against tanks, aircraft and steel plated warships.

Comment: I could even add that logistically the 1940's have much better transport vehicles and rail networks to be able to deploy troops faster and maintain supply lines over longer distances

Comment: Society has also changed in ways that make it easier to field armies. I doubt the HRE had a nation-wide system for *levee en masse*, for instance.

Comment: The primary problem with the HRE was organizational rather than technological or logistical. The constituent parts were not closely coupled or aligned the way a modern Empire, nation state or Federation is, so getting the manpower and logistical support for military action would be nightmarish.

Comment: @Thucydides while true for the time off the HRE, if they were brought into the 1940's even with good organization the technological difference would be too much to overcome

Comment: I think the Op is about a revived Holy Roman Empire existing in the 1940s and presumably using 1940s technology instead of 1800 technology or 1600 technology or 800 technology.